# Can't figure out this regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am making a regex that should run through this list and return the following values.

```
['-- /\ 11.5', '- /\ 11.5', '    x-small', '-- x-small', 'us 8.5']
```

Desired output:

```
['11.5', '11.5', 'x-small', 'x-small', 'us 8.5']
```

The regex I am using:

```
let testRe = /(?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+/
```

The output I am getting:

```
['11.5', '11.5', 'x-small', 'x-small', 'us']
```

As you can see the problem is with getting the space between us and 8.5 to return. I've tried a lot of different variations of the regex however I can't seem to get one that will work with the others.

I basically need a regex that: starts at the first number/letter in a string, picks up anything between the first and last number/letter, and returns it.

Thanks for any insight

Comment: what language do you use?

Comment: @mickmackusa it's quite common in `regex` to start with a comment and then transform it into an answer.

Comment: @mrzasa I am not new here and I answer a lot of regex questions.  The Comment box even states in the placeholder text that posting solutions as comments should be avoided.  There are many reasons why, but the biggest problem that I see is "Question Abandonment" -- then when someone puts the effort in to write up a complete answer, the OP is long gone and the volunteer who does the "right thing" is not rewarded.  "Pattern Dropping" is a problem on SO.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230676/hey-you-yeah-you-post-your-answers-as-answers-not-comments/296481

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Btw if you find my answer relevant, pls consider upvote :). If not - let me know what can be improved.

Comment: @mickmackusa, ok I wont do that in the future.

Comment: @lylecarlson this is javascript right?

Comment: @lylecarlson is there an "acceptable" answer on this page?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9.][a-zA-Z0-9.\- ]*[a-zA-Z0-9.\-])
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yeh0ys/3/)

Explanation:

- `[a-zA-Z0-9.]` matches letter digit or dot that should be at the beginning of the substring we are looking for
- `[a-zA-Z0-9.\- ]*` matches also a dash `-` and a space  (as both are allowed inside the substring). It can be repeated.
- `[a-zA-Z0-9.\-]` last allowed char again can be letter, digit or dot. Using that at the end limits scope of the repetition that is inside the and assures that we match until last allowed char.

Comment: @lylecarlson I can't speak for mrzasa, but, while a _"Thank You"_ is undoubtedly appreciated by many people, selecting an answer after it has solved your problem is a far more demonstrable show of gratitude, and also helps other users of the site by marking the problem as having a workable solution, and guiding them to it in search results.  Please refer to [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @lylecarlson: what CJK said. Also you should consider going through your past questions and upvoting/accepting answers where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

It appears from your sample input that you are trimming unwanted characters from the left-side of the strings.  For this reason, you can merely start matching once the first letter or number is encountered.  (If this logic does not hold true for all of your use cases, please provide more samples in your question that break this rule.)

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/S4QS8W/1)

Javascript Demo:

```js
let array = ['-- /\ 11.5', '- /\ 11.5', '    x-small', '-- x-small', 'us 8.5'];
let reTest = /[a-z\d].*/i;
for (var i=0, len=array.length; i<len; ++i) {
    document.write(array[i].match(reTest)+"<br>");
}
```